# How to check if a Python module is being imported within a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have some code in a Python package I wrote using this folder structure:

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   package1/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
```

In a seperate Jupyter notebook, I am importing some functionality from my package:

```
from foo.package1.module1 import a_function
```

However, I want to have some logic that changes how the package is used and how some of the functionality behaves depending on if it is being run inside of a Jupyter notebook kernel or not.

So in my `__init__.py`, I tried adding

```
def get_caller_filename() -> str:
    print(inspect.stack())
    filename = inspect.stack()[1].filename
    return filename

def perform_conditional_logic():
   if get_caller_filename().endswith(".ipynb"):
      ... # notebook specific logic
   else:
      ... # regular functionality

perform_conditional_logic() # this runs when the package is loaded
```

However, `get_caller_filename()` still resolves to `foo.package1.__init__.py`. I can inspect the  stack frames using `inspect.stack()`, but I see that the top level stack does not include my Jupyter notebook.

What's the best way of checking if my package code is being run in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `os.environ` or `sys.path`

If `sys.path` contains ipython you can assume you are running via jupyter
Please check `os.environ` also.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on how to do this?